Deveco assistant "Installation failed: 40. Invalid configuration file format." Error
I have tried to install a Hello World app for my Huawei watch Fit 3(liteWearble) In Deveco assistantSoftware. After signing and building the hap file when I click the hap file to install in my watch I get this error : Installation failed: 40. Invalid configuration file format
This error was already asked about by another user in the Huawei developer forums: (https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201108437583029024)
but my problem seems to be different as I have the icon.png and icon_small.png files in my resources.
Another reply suggested that the icon.bin file should be generated at entry/build/intermediates/js/release/source/lite/assets/entry/resources/base/, but I only have folders at entry/build/intermediates and I don't have a js folder.
Does anybody know what might be wrong, or what next steps I should take to diagnose the cause of this error?
